# What is the difference between queryReference and querySnapshot in firebase?

Tags: firebase

**What is the difference between queryReference and querySnapshot in firebase?**
// I searched many times on Google but I didn't get more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is just a pointer to a location in the database.  It doesn't contain any data.  It's just a path.  A snapshot contains the actual data as a result of performing a query using the reference.